# how to convert from yv12 to yuv420p

Tags: android, java-native-interface

On camera preview frame I get data in yv12 format on Android side. I need to convert it to YUV420P on jni side. How can I do it? As I have read from many sources in YUV420P format y samples appears first which is followed by u samples. u samples are followed by v sample. yv12 format is same as YUV420P except u and v samples appears in reverse order, that means y samples are followed by v and then u samples. Keeping that in mind I have used following swapping code to produce YUV420P data from yv12 data format before encoding.

```
avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)outframe, (uint8_t*)camData, codecCtx->pix_fmt, codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height);

uint8_t * buf_store = outframe->data[1];
outframe->data[1]=outframe->data[2];
outframe->data[2]=buf_store;
```

But it does not seems to be working. How should I adjust my code?

Answer (score 0):

Do, t use avpicture_fill. I have implemented in my application like this and its working fine

```
picture->linesize[0] = frameWidth;
picture->linesize[1] = frameWidth/2;
picture->linesize[2] = frameWidth/2;

picture->data[0] = camData;
picture->data[1] = camData + picture->linesize[0]*frameHeight+picture->linesize[1]*frameHeight/2;
picture->data[2] = camData + picture->linesize[0]*frameHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need this method:

```java
  //yv12 to yuv420p  
  public  static void swapYV12toI420(final byte[] yv12bytes, final byte[] i420bytes, int width, int height) {
        int size = width * height;
        int part = size / 4;
        System.arraycopy(yv12bytes, 0, i420bytes, 0, size);
        System.arraycopy(yv12bytes, size + part, i420bytes, size, part);
        System.arraycopy(yv12bytes, size, i420bytes, size + part, part);
    }
```

For every YV12 data packages you received, swap to i420.